# Haskell building a 'square' map with '#'s in especific cells and calculate empty cells

Tags: haskell

I'm doing a game for a class, and in one task I need to do a square (it's the 'map') that all I know is the dimension (size of each side) and then I want to calculate the cells I need to replace with a 'value'.

For example, a square with dimension 9 will look like this:

```
 # # # # # # # # #

 # _ _ v v v _ _ #

 # _ # V # v # _ #

 # v v v v v v v #

 # v # v # v # v #

 # v v v v v v v #

 # _ # v # v # _ #

 # _ _ v v v _ _ #

 # # # # # # # # #
```

- First and last lines allways full with `#` (walls)
- Second line and penultimate lines: allways begins with `#` and two empty spaces `_`.
- Third and antepenultimate lines: empty space in 2nd and before the last column, and `#` at every 2nd column.
- Then I have always one line without `#` in middle, and one with those `#` in every 2 spaces.

So, I need to build a function that calculate the `v`s. I have on that map, just receiving the `Dimension :: Int` (in this case was 9 and the function `calcV` (example of name to the function) would return 28)..

Below is my code that I tried. The square always has odd dimensions and equal or higher then 5, so I did the 5 case, and then a function that I expected would calculate what I want to all other possible values.
But it gives me:

> Exception: stack overflow in ghci

Does anyone know what I did wrong in this code?

```
calcv :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int

calcv 5 _ _ = 0

calcv d l c    -- the l and c will be given has 1(first line/first column) (d will be the dimension)

        | (l==1) = 0 + calcv d (l+1) 1
        | (l==(d-1)) || (l==2) && (c==1) || (c==2) || (c==3) || (c==(d-2)) || (c==(d-1)) = 0 + calcv d l (c+1)
        | (l==(d-1)) || (l==2) && (c>3) && (c<(d-2)) = if even c then 1 + calcv d l (c+1) else calcv d l (c+1) 
        | (l==(d-1)) || (l==2) && (c==d) = calcv d (l+1) 1
        | (l==3) || (l==(d-2)) && (c==1) || (c==2) || (c==3) || (c==(d-2)) || (c==(d-1)) = calcv d l (c+1)
        | (l==3) || (l==(d-2)) && (c>3) && (c<(d-2)) = if even c then 1 + calcv d l (c+1) else calcv d l (c+1)
        | (l==3) || (l==(d-2)) && (c==d) = calcv d (l+1) 1
        | (l==d) = 0
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'do a square'? Do you just want to write a representation to the console? How are you representing the location of the values?

Comment: Its just so you would know that the 'map' would be allways a square, so that's why i can build the map just from the dimension and the limitations i wrote before..

I need this function to calculate the 'v' s because building the map i need to take x values from a list of Int's that latter will replace those 'v's...

Comment: Also, the dimension is allways >= 5 and an odd number.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please consider reading the [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Here Stackoverflow we answer questions that are related to concrete errors/bugs/programming problems. Also tell us what you have tried to implement your "map" and what you have thought of doing, in short where you are stuck. Could you implement this problem in a language that is not haskell or is formulating the problem per se where you are stuck.

Comment: Hi, i have to do this in haskell..

I have started this by doing:
calcv :: Int -> Int
calcv d = (d*d) - (d*2) - (2*(d-6)) 
--d*d gives me full square
--d*2 takes first and last lines
--d-6 takes second and penultimate lines... 
I really dont know how to take the middle #'s... :s

Comment: Sounds a lot like an interview programming quiz. From Portland, OR.

Comment: I'm doing a school project actually man... :D

Comment: I added how i did it, its giving a error but i think it should be working...

Answer (score 0):

When faced with a problem like this, try to break it down into smaller pieces, and see how to express it with Haskell’s existing tools (like list comprehensions, `map`, `filter`, and `foldr`) before writing a recursive function.

First, you want to generate a square list of lists of length `n`, where every cell is some function of the row and column indices:

```
makeMap :: Int -> [[Char]]
makeMap n
  | even n || n < 5
  = error "makeMap: invalid size"

  | otherwise = [[cellAt row col | col <- [1 .. n]] | row <- [1 .. n]]
```

You could also define this with type `Int -> [Char]` if you don’t care about separating the rows, or if you want a single index into the whole map. You can also define it in terms of `map` rather than list comprehensions. I’ll leave those as exercises.

Now you can define the cell at a particular position by providing an implementation of `cellAt`:

```
  where
    cellAt :: Int -> Int -> Char
```

I won’t enumerate all the cases, since this is a homework problem, but here are a couple to get you started:

```
    -- Produce a border whenever row=1, col=1, row=n, or col=n.
    cellAt 1 _ = '#'
    cellAt _ 1 = '#'
    cellAt row col
      | row == n || col == n
      = '#'

    -- Handle other cases here.
      | ...
```

Then it looks like you want to count the number of `v` cells, which you can do by iterating over the map:

```
countV :: [[Char]] -> Int
countV rows = sum [sum [1 | 'v' <- row] | row <- rows]

calcV :: Int -> Int
calcV n = countV (makeMap n)
```

If your instructor wants a single function, a good exercise would be to manually inline the definitions of `countV` and `makeMap` into `calcV`. But it’s generally easier to write small, simple functions that you can compose to solve larger problems.

Comment: Thank you, i will be doing this since it can improve the code i have for now, i was able to make the calcv function by dividing it into 4 functions, one for second and penultime lines, one for third and antepenultime lines and one for odd lines and other for even lines, it works for all dimensions i can have(tested it over 1000 so i'm sure its ok). But the map can improve a lot with your sugestions, thanks a lot man

Comment: I just finished this code of you and its great, the map is well done and the calcV works perfectly...

Comment: The code is now smaller then what i had, and has a best presentation, thanks a lot man, but i have some doubts, i don't really understand the countV function, can you explain more or less what is happening in this function?

Comment: Oh, and it had an error, in the function cellAt i had to add one new Int, the n so the comparasion was possible.. So i added an Int in that function and on the makeMap function i changed one line: | otherwise = [[cellAt n row col | col <- [1 .. n]] | row <- [1 .. n]]
Just added the n so i could make the map using the n has a value..

Comment: Also change to this: 
calcV :: Int -> Int
calcV n = contV (makeMap n) where
    contV grelha = sum [sum [1 | 'v' <- row] | row <- grelha]

Even less code lines, i think its better this way right?

Comment: @Dost: The *inner* list comprehension, `sum [1 | 'v' <- row]` returns the number of cells in `row` that are equal to `'v'`, equivalent to `length (filter (== 'v') row)`. The *outer* list comprehension, `sum [... | row <- rows]` makes a list of the sum for each row, then takes *their* sum to return the total.

Comment: @Dost: As for your other questions: if `cellAt` is defined in the `where` clause of `makeMap`, it can see `n` in scope. Putting `contV` in the `where` clause of `calcV` makes sense, too. You can also write `calcV = contV . makeMap` using the composition operator `.`, which is very common.

Comment: thanks a lot man, i already had the contV inside calcV, now i just placed the cellAt in the where clause of makeMap, now i do what i want with 2 very easy to understand functions, its very good, small and easy to read. Thank you for helping me not just do but to understand what i'm doing! ;)